# Convert time series data to supervised learning problem

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-selection, feature-engineering, supervised-learning

I have a similar dataset like the one below. Each row represents a person and there are 3 different variables m1,m2,m3 with 3 measurements each.
I am trying to frame this time series problem as a supervised learning problem so i can train an SVM and/or random forest.

| id | Age | gender | m1_1 | m2_1 | m3_1 | m1_2 | m2_2 | m3_2 | m1_3 | m2_3 | m3_3 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | M | 12.4 | 34 | 12 | 13 | 324 | 34 | 34 | 232 | 12 | 0 |
| 2 | 30 | M | 123.4 | 324 | 2 | 32 | 32 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

My idea would be to reshape the data like this: Note that I only did for the first row on the dataset above

| id | Age | gender | m1 | m2 | m3 | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | M | 12.4 | 34 | 12 | 0 |
| 1 | 20 | M | 13 | 324 | 34 | 0 |
| 1 | 20 | M | 34 | 232 | 12 | 0 |

Basically, if there are 3 measurements per variable, I'd have 3 rows to reflect this information.

Am I going in the right direction with this approach? If not, could you point me to the right direction?

Thank you for taking your time in advance.

Comment: So m1, m2 and m3 are variables taken over time? If so, how you have arranged your data is the standard way to transform a time series problem that can be handled by typical supervised learning problems. However, this is assuming that you know what m1, m2, and m3 will be in the forecast period before observing the target variable.

Comment: Yes, m1,m2,m3 are measurements taken over time. I am not sure I understand what you mean by "this is assuming that you know what m1, m2, and m3 will be in the forecast period before observing the target variable".

Do you mean that when I observe the second instance of m1, I should have a value for the first instance of m1?  I used the full data shaped like the one above in a simple SVM model using GridSearchCV and the score for each iteration of GridSearch remains the same. I am not sure it is correct. A side note is that my data is unbalanced. About 87% are label 0 and 12% label 1.

Comment: Well, I am assuming you wish to predict the next periods value right? Like the target variable for the 4th time period, or even further? Then if you are using m1, m2 and m3 as predictors it is necessary that you know these values m1, m2 and m3 beforehand. If you know these values beforehand then there is no problem as far as I can tell data arrangement wise.

Comment: Also, how are you validating the model? Are you respecting the time aspect of your data, say, splitting the dataset by time?

Comment: No, I am not trying to predict the next value in the series. I'm trying to predict if the output is 1 or 0 by looking at the measurements. 

No, I just did the regular test_train_split as below:
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.4). and did the following for the GridSearchCV :   svm = SVC(gamma=1)    
# Instantiate the GridSearchCV object and run the search
parameters = {'C':[0.1, 1, 10], 'gamma':[0.00001, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1]}
searcher = GridSearchCV(svm, parameters, scoring='accuracy', verbose=10)
searcher.fit(X_train, y_train)

Comment: Sorry for the formatting on my response above. Do I need to split the data in a different way that what I'm currently doing?

Comment: In addition, this is what I got for the .score() function on the train and test sets.
Best CV accuracy 0.8778052776141401
Test accuracy of best grid search hypers: 0.8775118392422885

Comment: One thing that I notice here by inspecting my train and test sets is that the data is just random split as expected from the function. I don't know if my assumption is correct but should the data be split into blocks of 3 rows since they are part of the same measurements? Not sure how the split has to be.

Comment: Okay - I think I was a bit confused about the wording here. One important question I suppose I have: the target variable 0/1...if a person is a "1" does this mean they become a 1 at the last observation time? For example, for person id 1, you have 0, 0, 0, implying that they had 0 at time 1, 0 at time 2, and 0 at time 3. For person id 2, does a "1" imply 0, 0, 1 (they became positive at time 3) or is the intention instead 1, 1, 1, as in, they were "positive" at all observation points in time?

Comment: Perhaps it will be more helpful if I describe my problem with more details.
Each row of my dataset describes a patient and contains 8 entries for measurements that doctors took during the day.
Ex: ....|hr_tb1 | hr_tb2 | hr_tb3 | hr_tb4 | hr_tb5 | hr_tb6 | hr_tb7 | hr_tb8 | sbp_tb1 sbp_tb2 | sbp_tb3 |  sbp_tb4 | sbp_tb5 |  sbp_tb6 | sbp_tb7 | sbp_tb8| inhospital_mortality **Label 0 if the patient didn't die and 1 if they died.**

Thus, the label indicates if the patient had died or not in the end of the day.

Comment: I forgot to mention that those 8 measurements are taken every 3 hours.